# MYSQL Selecting oldest date record for each unique event

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

I have the following two tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events_dates` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `start_time` time NOT NULL,
  `end_time` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `event_id` (`event_id`),
  KEY `date` (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Where the link is event_id

What I want is to retrieve all unique event records with their respective event dates ordered by the smallest date ascending within a certain period

Basically the following query does exactly what I want

```
SELECT Event.id, Event.title, EventDate.date, EventDate.start_time, EventDate.end_time
FROM
    events AS Event
        JOIN
    com_events_dates AS EventDate 
    ON (Event.id = EventDate.event_id AND EventDate.date = (
        SELECT MIN(MinEventDate.date) FROM events_dates AS MinEventDate
        WHERE MinEventDate.event_id = Event.id AND MinEventDate.date >= CURDATE() # AND `MinEventDate`.`date` < '2013-02-27'
        )
    )
WHERE
    EventDate.date >= CURDATE() # AND `EventDate`.`date` < '2013-02-27'
ORDER BY EventDate.date ASC , EventDate.start_time ASC , EventDate.end_time DESC
LIMIT 20
```

This query is the result of multiple attempts at further improving the slow time this initially had (1.5 seconds) when i wanted to use group by and other subqueries. Its the fastest one yet but considering that there are 1400 event records and 10000 event records in total, the query takes 400+ ms time to process, also I run a count based on this (for paging purposes) that takes a lot of time as well.
Strangely enough omitting the EventDate condition in the main where clause causes this to be even higher 1s+.

Is there anything I can do to improve this or a different approach at the table structure?

Comment: How does it perform without the order by clause?

Comment: Without the order by it performs a great deal faster but I really need them sorted that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify to anyone else... the "#" in MySQL acts as a continuation comment and is basically ignored in the query, it is not an "AND EventDate.Date < '2013-02-27'".  That said, it appears you want a list of all events COMING UP that have not yet happened.  I would start with a simple "prequery" that just grabs all events and the minimum date based on the event date not happening yet.  Then join that result to the other tables to get the rest of the fields you want

```
SELECT
      E.ID,
      E.Title,
      ED2.`date`,
      ED2.Start_Time,
      ED2.End_Time
   FROM
      ( SELECT
              ED.Event_ID,
              MIN( ED.`date` ) as MinEventDate
           from 
              Event_Dates ED
           where
              ED.`date` >= curdate()
           group by
              ED.Event_ID ) PreQuery
      JOIN Events E
         ON PreQuery.Event_ID = E.ID
      JOIN Event_Dates ED2
         ON PreQuery.Event_ID = ED2.Event_ID
         AND PreQuery.MinEventDate = ED2.`date`
   ORDER BY
      ED2.`date`,
      ED2.Start_Time,
      ED2.End_Time DESC
   LIMIT 20
```

Your table has redundant index on event ID, just by different names.  Calling the name of an index `date` does not mean that's the column being indexed.  The value(s) in parens ( `event_id` ) is what the index is built on.

So, I would change your create table to...

```
KEY `date` ( `event_id`, `date`, `start_time` )
```

Or, to manually create an index.

```
Create index ByEventAndDate on Event_Dates ( `event_id`, `date`, `start_time` )
```

Comment: I've tweaked it this way and it definetly runs more than twice as fast.
However the prequery needed the group by Event_ID, otherwise it selected me only the single lowest date of all events

Comment: @zakel, glad it worked, I revised the 'group by' in the answer... sorry I missed it, but glad you easily identified it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about optimization, it is helpful to include execution plans when possible.

By the way try this ones (if you are not tried it already):

```
SELECT 
  Event.id, 
  Event.title, 
  EventDate.date, 
  EventDate.start_time, 
  EventDate.end_time
FROM
    (select e.id, e.title, min(date) as MinDate
        from events_dates as ed
          join events as e on e.id = ed.event_id
        where date >= CURDATE() and date < '2013-02-27'
        group by e.id, e.title) as Event
  JOIN events_dates AS EventDate ON Event.id = EventDate.event_id 
    and Event.MinDate = EventDate.date
ORDER BY EventDate.date ASC , EventDate.start_time ASC , EventDate.end_time DESC
LIMIT 20
;

#assuming event_dates.date for greater event_dates.id always greater

SELECT 
  Event.id, 
  Event.title, 
  EventDate.date, 
  EventDate.start_time, 
  EventDate.end_time
FROM
    (select e.id, e.title, min(ed.id) as MinID
        from events_dates as ed
          join events as e on e.id = ed.event_id
        where date >= CURDATE() and date < '2013-02-27'
        group by e.id, e.title) as Event
  JOIN events_dates AS EventDate ON Event.id = EventDate.event_id 
    and Event.MinID = EventDate.id
ORDER BY EventDate.date ASC , EventDate.start_time ASC , EventDate.end_time DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Your first solution is very similar to DRapp's one. 
Unfortunately the second is not going to work because the date can be smaller for a higher id.